# Command that can show all file contents that has "random_" word of the file name

Tags: ubuntu

I need some help , Is there a command that can show all file contents that has "random_" word of the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear which files you want to select but this simple command might be the answer :

```
cat *random_*
```